# Как реализовать кнопку "наверх"?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Собственно нужно чтобы кнопка при нажатии имела такой вид до момента пока не пропадет вовсе. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Саму кнопку и её функционал я сделал так:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
  }
});
$('.scrollup').click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 600);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.scrollup {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 140px;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: #47a759;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.scrollup:before,
.scrollup:after {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 4px 4px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 12px;
  top: 32%;
  margin: auto;
}
.scrollup:before {
  transform: translate(21px, 1px) rotate(45deg);
}
.scrollup:after {
  transform: translate(18px, 0) rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollup"></div>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Как это всё реализовать? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Добавляем класс animate во время анимации. Дополнительную стилизацию добавлять к нему.

```
$('.scrollup').click(function() {
  var self = this;
  $(self).addClass('animate');
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 600, function() {
    $(self).removeClass('animate')
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Scroll to top
$('.scrollup').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
     $('#scroll').removeClass('scrollclick').addClass('scrollup');
  }
});    
$('.scrollup').click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 600);
    $('#scroll').removeClass('scrollup').addClass('scrollclick');
      return false;
    });

    <div class="scrollup" id="scroll"></div>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

При нажатии будут классы меняться с **scrollup** на **scrollclick**, а при поднятии наоборот